# Add specific lines connecting the cells to a table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have the following code for a table

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
{\def\arraystretch{1.5}\tabcolsep=10pt \large
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
\multirow{2}{*}{\scalebox{1.5}{$\square$ Modul 1}}& Exercise 1\\
&Exercise 2\\
\multirow{4}{*}{\scalebox{1.5}{$\square$ Modul 2}}& Exercise 3\\
&Exercise 4\\
&Exercise 5\\
&Exercise 6\\
\multirow{2}{*}{\scalebox{1.5}{$\square$ Modul 3}}& Exercise 7\\
&Exercise 8\\
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image: Table without lines]

But I want to add some lines to let it look like this (I drew the lines by Gimp):

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use `\tikzmarknode` from the `tikzmark` Ti*k*Z library, then `-|` and `|-` drawing operations between the appropriate node anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The lines are drawn with Tikz by using the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` under the cells, rows and columns of the array.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\large
\begin{NiceTabular}{cw{c}{4cm}l}
\Block[name=modul1]{2-1}{$\square$ Modul 1}
   && Exercise 1\\
   && Exercise 2\\
\Block[name=modul2]{4-1}{$\square$ Modul 2}
   && Exercise 3\\
   && Exercise 4\\
   && Exercise 5\\
   && Exercise 6\\
\Block[name=modul3]{2-1}{$\square$ Modul 3}
   && Exercise 7\\
   && Exercise 8\\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [dotted,thick] 
        (modul1.east) -- ++(3cm,0) |- (1-|last) 
        (modul1.east) -- ++(3cm,0) |- ([yshift=0.5mm]5-|last) ;
  \draw 
        (modul2.east) -- ++(1cm,0) |- (3-|last) 
        (modul2.east) -- ++(1cm,0) |- (7-|last) ;
  \draw [dashed]
        (modul3.east) -- ++(3cm,0) |- ([yshift=-0.5mm]5-|last) 
        (modul3.east) -- ++(3cm,0) |- (9-|last) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This looks like the very thing I searched for, but when I try to compile it (with PDFLatex) i get a nicematrix package error: "The key 'name' is unknown for the command \Block."

Comment: You don't have the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation. If you use Overleaf, please note that Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. In that case, you should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not the permission to install/update software. But I solved my problem now, by defining tikzmarknodes and used your code for the tikzpicture. The use of the nicematrix package becomes obsolete then.